# Can't send JSON to server

Tags: jquery, json, post

I'm having trouble getting the server to recognize a JSON POST request since I changed the code a bit.  Previously, a POST request was made for each iteration of a for loop, but now I've changed it to include a multi-level JSON array.

```
var json=[];

for (var i=0; i < tourList.length; i++){
  var data = tourList[i];
  json.push({latitude: data.position.ab, longitude: data.position.cb, filename: data.title, stopNum: i});
}

var results= JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(json);
console.log(results);

//this code was previously inside the for loop above, moved it outside
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../includes/phpscripts.php?action=postTour",
  data: results,
  datatype: "json",
  beforeSend: function(x){
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType){
      x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
  },
  success: function(data){
    if (data == "success")
      console.log("Tour update successful");
    else 
      console.log("Tour update failed");
  }
});
```

At this point in time, tourList has a length of 6 and `results` is based on Google Maps marker clicks and produces this in Firebug:

```
[
  {"latitude":43.682211,"longitude":-70.45070499999997,"filename":"../panos/photos/1-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","stopNum":0},
  {"latitude":43.6822,"longitude":-70.45076899999998,"filename":"../panos/photos/2-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","stopNum":1},
  {"latitude":43.682219,"longitude":-70.450828,"filename":"../panos/photos/3-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","stopNum":2},
  {"latitude":43.68218,"longitude":-70.45088699999997,"filename":"../panos/photos/4-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","stopNum":3}
]
```

However, nothing shows up as a `$_POST` variable, as `$_POST` shows up as `type: array[0]` in the debugger.  So I have no data set to run `json_decode` upon.  From what I can see, the JSON is valid.  What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the string as a post var.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../includes/phpscripts.php?action=postTour",
  data: {"json": results},
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function(x){
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType){
      x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
  },
  success: function(data){
    if (data == "success")
      console.log("Tour update successful");
    else 
      console.log("Tour update failed");
  }
});
```

Access the json with `$_POST["json"]`

I'm not sure what you are returning from your PHP, however, if it is json, it will never be equal to `"success"`

Edit: One more issue. Your `datatype` parameter should be `dataType`, and this parameter only defines what dataType is being returned from PHP, not what you are sending it.

Comment: Thanks!  That `success` is the result from an echo statement and is part of my logging process.

Comment: In that case, remove the `datatype` parameter since you aren't returning JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You have no key/value being sent , only value

In ajax change to:

```
 data: {results:results},
```

in php

```
$results=$_POST['results']
```

Now you can use `json_deocde($results)`